# Proving that copulas are Lipschitz continuous

Tags: lipschitz-functions, copula

A copula is a function $C:[0,1]^2\to[0,1]$ such that $C(x,0)=C(0,x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, $C(x,1)=C(1,x)=x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, and
\begin{equation}\label{ineq}
 C(x_2,y_2)-C(x_1,y_2)-C(x_2,y_1)+C(x_1,y_1)\ge0\tag{*}
\end{equation}
for all $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)\in[0,1]^2$ with $x_1\le x_2$ and $y_1\le y_2$. I am trying to show that a copula is Lipschitz continuous in the following sense:
$$
 |C(x_2,y_2)-C(x_1,y_1)|
 \le|x_2-x_1|+|y_2-y_1|
$$
for all $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in[0,1]^2$.

Suppose that $x_2\ge x_1$ and $y_2\ge y_1$. Using the definition of a copula, we have that
$$
x_2-x_1-C(x_2,y_1)+C(x_1,y_1)\ge0
$$
and
$$
y_2-y_1-C(x_2,y_2)+C(x_2,y_1)\ge0.
$$
Adding these two inequalities, we obtain
$$
C(x_2,y_2)-C(x_1,y_1)
\le x_2-x_1+y_2-y_1.
$$
Since copulas are increasing in each argument, $
C(x_2,y_2)
\ge C(x_2,y_1)
\ge C(x_1,y_1)
$
so that
$
C(x_2,y_2)-C(x_1,y_1)\ge0
$
and hence
$$
|C(x_2,y_2)-C(x_1,y_1)|\le x_2-x_1+y_2-y_1,
$$
when $x_1\le x_2$ and $y_1\le y_2$.

> We also need to consider the case when $x_1\le x_2$ but $y_1\ge y_2$. If I understand correctly, inequality \eqref{ineq} is not valid in this case and I am not sure how to proceed. How can we proceed with the proof when $x_1\le x_2$ but $y_1\ge y_2$?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: well, if you assume $x_2\geq x_1$ and $y_2\geq y_1$ then trivially $C(x2,y2)−C(x1,y1)\geq 0\geq -(x2−x1+y2−y1)$.

Comment: However, sligthly more complicated case is when $x_2\geq x_1, y_1\geq y_2$. Then, you need to divide the $[0,1]^2$ into two parts.

Comment: @AlbertParadek Thanks for your comment! How does it follow that $C(x_2,y_2)-C(x_1,y_1)\ge0$? A copula is non-decreasing in each argument, right? Can we conclude that $C(x_2,y_2)-C(x_1,y_1)\ge0$ if $x_2\ge x_1$ and $y_2\ge y_1$?

Comment: As you said, A copula is non-decreasing in each argument .Therefore, $C(x2, y2)\geq C(x2, y1)\geq C(x1, y1)$. Hence, $C(x2, y2)-C(x1, y1)\geq 0$

Comment: @AlbertParadek Thanks for drawing my attention to the case when $x_2\ge x_1$ but $y_2\le y_1$ (I edited the question accordingly). If I understand correctly, the inequality in the definition of a copula is no longer applicable in this case. You mentioned that $[0,1]^2$ needs to be divided into two parts. Could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $x_1\le x_2$ but $y_1\ge y_2$. Then either  $C(x_2, y_2)\geq C(x_1, y_1)$ or $C(x_2, y_2)\leq C(x_1, y_1)$. Take the case when $C(x_2, y_2)\geq C(x_1, y_1)$.  Then, you want to prove that

$$
C(x_2, y_2)- C(x_1, y_1)\leq x_2-x_1 + y_1-y_2.
$$
From the marginal monotonicity you get

$$
C(x_2, y_2)- C(x_1, y_1)\leq C(x_2, y_2)- C(x_1, y_2). 
$$

Now, you are in the previous setting, i.e. holds that

$$
C(x_2, y_2)- C(x_1, y_2)\leq x_2-x_1. 
$$
Hence, $C(x_2, y_2)- C(x_1, y_1)\leq x_2-x_1. $
In the other case when $C(x_2, y_2)\leq C(x_1, y_1)$, we obtain the same
$$
C(x_2, y_2)- C(x_1, y_1)\leq y_1-y_2. 
$$

Hence, together,
$$
C(x_2, y_2)- C(x_1, y_1) \leq \max(x_2-x_1,y_1-y_2) \leq x_2-x_1+y_1-y_2. 
$$